Plotting the Electrostatic Potential from VASP
I am currently looking into possibilities to plot the electrostatic potential in VASP, very similar to how user Jaafar Mehrez did in this answer.
P4VASP seems to have been discontinued and VESTA doesn't run on my system because of an issue with libwebkit2gtk-4.0.
Looking at the LOCPOT file, it looks like pandas and matplotlib could do the job relatively easily, so I am assuming some solution for this outside of VESTA and P4VASP already exists.
Does anyone have any recommendations, preferably open source?

Did you look at SISL?

yes I looked into it, I do not seem to be able to find the part where they explain how to plot the electrostatic potential though.

@JannisErhard, I used to get the data for ESP using vaspkit (vaspkit.com/tutorials.html#potential-related), it can extract the data you are looking for and give you .dat file that you can plot using your preferred plotting tools. As you have mentioned in your question, it is straightforward to get the data from LOCPOT, if you prefer source codes, some post-processing scripts do exist, for instance (https://github.com/rjacobs914/VASP-Tools/blob/master/VASP_PostProcessing.py) has analyzer for LOCPOT, I have also found (https://github.com/SMTG-Bham/surfaxe) supports potential analysis.

thank you for this suggestion. vaspkit can in deed do what I am looking for, the only problem for me is that it is not open source.

As @Camps says, you could use sisl for this.
The procedure is relatively simple:
sgrid LOCPOT --out locpot.cube

and then you can plot the cube file using your favourite tool, I would recommend VMD or XCrySDen.
The sgrid command also allows one to do averages on planes, e.g.:
sgrid LOCPOT --average x --average y --out locpot.dat

will create the average potential along the z-direction (an x [Ang], y [Potential] data file).
Altogether sgrid is just a wrapper of internal mechanisms in sisl which allows greater variability of what can be done.
But that would be a first start to get something tangible.
Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of sisl.

Besides the sisl package as explained in the answer of nickpapior.
There is also a different package called Electron Density Plotter (EDP). Examples of z-averaging or line extraction are given in the documentation of this C++ command line package.
Looking at the pipeline of this program as shown in the JOSS paper, it can save z-averaging into txt files. If you do not like the standard visualization of EDP you can thus use your favorite visualizer with this txt file.
Edit: EDP plots the electron density and not the electrostatic potential as described in the question.
